# how to redirect to an action of a controller from a gsp in a grails application

Tags: grails, redirect, controller, gsp

My requirement is, I'm having a gsp where using a `<g:if>` tag I'm checking for a condition.
If that condition satisfies, then I have to redirect the control automatically to an action in a controller.
How I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that in the gsp and not in the controller with `redirect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript like:

```
<g:if ...>
<g:javascript>
window.location.href = '<g:createLink ... >';
</g:javascript>
</g:if>
```

Btw, it's much easier and better to do it in controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things.

I did it using a custom tag that had a closure checking if for example a logged in user had a certain role or something, then you can do the redirect from your closure.

The you just put the tag in you gsp-page.